# call asm sqrtsd under a c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, inline-assembly, sqrt

Under visual 2012 how can I call the sqrtsd asm function in a c++ project

I can't find it via google

something like :

```
double mySqrt(double val)
{
__asm
{
  ...
  sqrstd...
}
}
```

EDIT:

in 32bit mode

Comment: Something like `push argument \r\n call sqrt`, however you'll need 1. the mangled name of `std::sqrt()`, 2. a good assembly tutorial.

Comment: ...and not 64-bit target

Comment: A related question [Is it possible to roll a significantly faster version of sqrt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637700/is-it-possible-to-roll-a-significantly-faster-version-of-sqrt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think doing this is a somewhat academic excercise, as it's unlikely to have any actual benefit, and quite likely a penalty. However:

```
double mySqrt(double val)
{
    double retu;

    __asm
    {
        sqrtsd xmm1, val
        movsd retu, xmm1
    }
    return retu;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not using sqrt function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/ which will be portable ?

By default VS 2012 will replace sqrt() by `__libm_sse2_sqrt_precise`. But if you compile with `/fp:fast` it will replace by `sqrtsd`

Comment: I would like to be sure of the asm code, cause I can have a call to __libm_sse2_sqrt_precise

Comment: Compile with /fp:fast to get the compiler to directly emit sqrtpd without using a library function.

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not be able to use inline assembler, as other answers have indicated.

There are, however so called intrinsics for SSE (and MMX and others):

[intrinsic functons for MS VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The one for `sqrtsd` is [_mm_sqrt_sd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1994h1ay%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You'll obviously have to read a few of the other pages as well to be able to put together the whole thing. Intrinsics is the recommended way by Microsoft to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

what you want, the feature that you are looking for, it's called "inline assembly", meaning assembly inside a C/C++ program basically, Visual Studio doesn't offer a good support for this, for x64 bit platform it doesn't offer this feature at all.

http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0015/

You probably want to switch to a better compiler.