# Implementation SQRT in C#

Tags: c#, sqrt

I need to know how is Math.Sqrt square root function implemented in c# by Microsoft. Is there anyone who knows it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Computation

Comment: I bet it's a native function. Anything else would be a bit slow

Comment: I bet Jon Skeet knows.

Comment: Sqrt is computed (as a single ASM instruction) directly in the CPU, either the x87 unit or an SSE instruction.

Comment: Check out this question, you will find answers in it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931853/c-sharp-math-sqrt-implementation

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/753b6659-4a8a-4389-b805-126ae670aba9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# calls the native `sqrt()` from `<cmath>` C++.

Getting the source code for CLR to prove it!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Computation) has full information on square root(Algorithm level)