# Casting from long double to unsigned long long appears broken in the MSVC C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long double test = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    cout << "1: " << test << endl;
    unsigned long long test2 = test;
    cout << "2: " << test2 << endl;
    cout << "3: " << (unsigned long long)test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with GCC g++ (7.5.0) and running produces the following output as expected:

```
1: 1.84467e+19
2: 18446744073709551615
3: 18446744073709551615
```

However compiling this with the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler (16.8.31019.35, both 64-bit and 32-bit) and running produces the following output:

```
1: 1.84467e+19
2: 9223372036854775808
3: 9223372036854775808
```

When casting a value to an `unsigned long long`, the MSVC compiler won't give a value lager than the max of a (signed) `long long`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Am I running into a compiler limitation that I do not know about?

Does anyone know of a possible workaround to this problem?

Comment: what is "the problem" you need a workaround for? If you do not cast there is no problem.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to take a long double that contains a value greater than 0x8000000000000000 and convert in to a unsigned long long that contains the same values. The printing of the values is just to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: In msvc a long double is the same as double and is 8 bytes not 16.

Comment: try to take a look at `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` and relatives. This might shed some light on it. What do you want to do when the value of the `long double` cannot fit in a `unsigned long long` ?

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks for pointing this out. I was not aware of it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I am not sure I understand. `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` is equal to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, so it should fit just fine. I am handling the case where it cannot fit separately.

Comment: yeah sorry I was looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what is going on. Because a MSVC `long double` is really just a `double`, it does not have enough precision to contain the exact value of 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. When this value is stored in the `long double` it gets "rounded" to a value that is lager than 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. This then causes undefined behaviour when converting to an `unsigned long long`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ManInBlack Note that it is perfectly fine to answer your question yourself and that comment looks like it should be an answer.

Comment: @drescherjm gcc doesn't emulate anything, it's using the 80-bit extended precision type in x86 and pad to 12 or 16 bytes for alignment. [Why did Microsoft abandon long double data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7120710/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are double and long double completely the same on my 64 bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922216/why-are-double-and-long-double-completely-the-same-on-my-64-bit-machine)

Comment: @phuclv thanks. I didn't know how it accomplished this given the CPU does not have full quad double. I see there is info about that here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing undefined behaviour because, as pointed out in the comments, a `long double` is the same as a `double` in MSVC and the 'converted' value of your `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (or `ULLONG_MAX`) actually gets 'rounded' to a slightly (but *significantly*) larger value, as can be seen in the following code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    long double test = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    cout << 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFuLL << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(16) << endl;
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551616.0000000000000000
```

Thus, when converting that floating-point value back to an `unsigned long long`, you are falling foul of the conversion rules specified in [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/conversions-from-floating-point-types?view=msvc-170):

> - For conversion to **`unsigned long`** or **`unsigned long long`**, the result of converting an out-of-range value may be some value other than the
>   highest or lowest representable value. Whether the result is a
>   sentinel or saturated value or not depends on the compiler options and
>   target architecture. Future compiler releases may return a saturated
>   or sentinel value instead.

This UB can be further 'verified' (for want of a better term) by switching to the clang-cl compiler that can be used from within Visual Studio. For your *original* code, this then gives `0` for the values on both the "2" and "3" output lines.

Assuming that the clang (LLVM) compiler is not bound by the aforementioned "Microsoft Rules," we can, instead, fall back on [the C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 7.10 Floating-integral conversions      [conv.fpint]
>
> <sup>1</sup>     A prvalue of a floating-point type
> can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion
> truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is
> undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the
> destination type.

Answer (score 6):

Because a MSVC `long double` is really just a `double` (as pointed out by @drescherjm in the comments), it does not have enough precision to contain the exact value of 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. When this value is stored in the `long double` it gets "rounded" to a value that is lager than 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. This then causes undefined behaviour when converting to an `unsigned long long`.