# IEEE 754 and float precision

Tags: c, floating-point, cpu, 32bit-64bit, ieee-754

Does it make any difference in having a 32 or 64-bit CPU in the amount of precision that IEEE 754 provides?

I mean when programming in C whether the size of `float`, `double` and `long double` are different between a 32 or 64-bit CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference, you can confirm this by checking `sizeof(float)` across both architectures. If you need greater precision use `double`.

Comment: So does not offer any advantage to C programmers of mathematics applications a 64bit CPU?

Comment: Do not quote me on this, but `double` performance on 64bit should be faster then 32bit depending on what you are doing since a double value is 64 bits long. It also depends on the FPU.

Comment: 64-bit means a wider (faster) bus.  So there would be some speed up there. 64-bit FPU would also process doubles better.

Answer (score 4):

In most architectures that use IEEE-754, `float` and `double` are exact 32 and 64-bit types corresponding to single and double precision respectively. Therefore the **precision is the same whether you're on a 32 or a 64-bit computer**. The exceptions are some microcontrollers with non-standard-compliant C compilers where both `double` and `float` are the same and contain 32 bits

OTOH **`long double` support varies depending on system**. On x86 most implementations will utilize the hardware [80-bit extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) type (often padded to 12 or 16 bytes in order to maintain alignment), except MSVC where [`long double` is just an alias for `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7120710/995714). On other architectures `long double` are often implemented as either

1. The same type as `double`, or
2. 128-bit [IEEE 754-2008 quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format), or
3. 128-bit [double-double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic)

While the second way increases both range and precision significantly compared to `double`, it's also often significantly slower due to the lack of hardware support

The `double-double` method results in a type with in the same range but twice the precision of `double`, with the advantage of hardware `double` support, i.e. you don't need to implement entirely in software like quadruple precision. However it's not IEEE-754 compliant

If you're doing a lot of math on [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) or [arm](/questions/tagged/arm), moving to 64-bit would benefit because of the increased number of registers, SSE2/Neon available by default... which improves performance compared to the 32-bit version, unlike most other architectures where 64-bit programs often run slower due to bigger pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It is common to most 32-bit and 64-bit machines for `float` to be IEEE-754 32-bit floating point, and `double` to be IEEE-754 64-bit floating point. Some implementations might use the IEEE-754 80-bit type as double (or long double).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `float` and `double` map to IEEE-754 single-precision and double-precision numbers respectively, then no, there is no difference.

`long double` may be a different story, however, since compilers may choose to pad it to an even size.