# Wrong C++ long double min/max values using numeric_limits in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, long-double, numeric-limits

*Using Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.4.2 with the latest stuff it comes with on 64bit Win10.*

While testing various datatype limits ran into a weird bug, numeric_limits can't distinguish between double and long double min/max values. Displays more reasonable results using NetBeans with default GNU Mac tool chain.

```
    // Type limits: float
    std::cout 
        << "MIN float        " << numeric_limits<float>::min() << "\n"
        << "MAX float        " << numeric_limits<float>::max() << "\n"
        << "MIN double       " << numeric_limits<double>::min() << "\n"
        << "MAX double       " << numeric_limits<double>::max() << "\n"
        << "MIN long double  " << numeric_limits<long double>::min() << "\n"
        << "MAX long double  " << numeric_limits<long double>::max() << "\n";
```

Console Output

> ```
> MIN float        1.17549e-38
> MAX float        3.40282e+38
> MIN double       2.22507e-308
> MAX double       1.79769e+308
> MIN long double  2.22507e-308    // NetBeans on Mac 3.3621e-4932
> MAX long double  1.79769e+308    // NetBeans on Mac 1.18973e+4932
> ```

Comment: What value do you expect for `numeric_limits<long double>::max()` and why?

Comment: Related: [Why did Microsoft abandon long double data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120710/why-did-microsoft-abandon-long-double-data-type)

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019).

Comment: _"Should be 3.3621e-4932"_ According to whom?

Comment: NetBeans running GNU Mac default tool chain gives me those values using numeric_limits. Sorry for the ambiguities, haven't used stack before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The c++ standard only requires `long double` to have at least the precision of `double`, so there's nothing wrong with the output of your program.

Quote from the standard (§3.9.1, lit 8):

> There are three floating point types: float,double, and long double.The type double provides at least as much precision as float, and the type **long double provides at least as much precision as double**.The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double. The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined. Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types. Specializations of the standard template std::numeric_limits (18.3) shall specify the maximum and minimum values of each arithmetic type for an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`long double` and `double` are equivalent using Visual Studio.

Both `double` and `long double` are containing 64 bits: 1 for sign, 11 for the exponent, and 52 for the mantissa. Its range is +/-1.7E308 with at least 15 digits of precision.

This is in correspondence with the c++ standard. It only requires `long double` to have at least the precision of `double`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-language/type-long-double?view=vs-2019) for a official reference.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "identical". They are different types.

Comment: Yeah, "equivalent" would be more accurate, but even then there's room for misunderstanding (as it suggests that the lexical keyword sequences `long double` and `double` are equivalent, which they aren't)

Comment: "`long double` and `double` are identical using Windows" is also not correct. MinGW-w64 has a `long double` with higher precision than plain `double`.