# Long double output as 0.000000000000 in c lang

Tags: c, clang, double, codeblocks, long-double

I am coding in *Code::Blocks*, in the C programming language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float var1 = 3.145926535897932;
    double var2 = 3.145926535897932;
    long double var3 = 3.14159265389793213456;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long double));
    printf("%.16f\n", var1);
    printf("%.16f\n", var2);
    printf("%.21Lf\n", var3);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting output as:-

```
4
8
16
3.1459264755249023
3.1459265358979320
0.000000000000000000000
```

Why am I getting `0.000000000000000000000` instead of `3.14159265389793213456`, does my system does not support `long double` or is there a mistake in my code?
And if `long double` does not work in my system how it is able to give output of size of `long double`?

Comment: Your code looks (mostly) fine.  Some systems do indeed have trouble with `printf` and `long double` or `long long`.

Comment: You've got a slight problem with the first three printfs, because `sizeof` doesn't return `int`.  To make it fully portable, you need `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(float))`, or `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(float))`, or something like that.

Comment: On my system, the code prints `4
8
16
3.1459264755249023
3.1459265358979320
3.141592653897931963769`, more or less as expected.

Comment: So it looks like what's happening is that your *compiler* supports `long double`, but your *C runtime library* (and specifically the implementation of `printf` in it) does not.

Comment: Possibly delayed effects of the undefined behaviour from using `%d` to print `size_t` types. Use `%zu` for the first 3 `printf` and try again.

Comment: @AdrianMole The C libraries that don't support `%Lf` are very likely to not support `%zd` either (since both were added in C99). I would recommend `%lu` with an `(unsigned long)` cast instead.

Comment: What compiler and version is CodeBlocks using?

Answer (score 0):

On my system (OS/X with clang), I get the expected output:

```
4
8
16
3.1459264755249023
3.1459265358979320
3.141592653897931963769
```

Yet the compiler produces many warnings:

```
clang -O3 -funsigned-char -std=c11 -Weverything -Wno-padded -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-vla -Wno-missing-nor
eturn -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings  -lm -lcurses -o 220306-longdouble 220306-longdouble.c
220306-longdouble.c:4:18: warning: implicit conversion loses floating-point precision: 'double' to 'float' [-Wconversion]
    float var1 = 3.145926535897932;
          ~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
220306-longdouble.c:6:24: warning: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'double' to 'long double'
      [-Wdouble-promotion]
    long double var3 = 3.14159265389793213456;
                ~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
220306-longdouble.c:7:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(float));
            ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %lu
220306-longdouble.c:8:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(double));
            ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %lu
220306-longdouble.c:9:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long double));
            ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %lu
220306-longdouble.c:10:23: warning: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'float' to 'double'
      [-Wdouble-promotion]
    printf("%.16f\n", var1);
    ~~~~~~            ^~~~
6 warnings generated.
```

Here are the explanations:

- the value produced by the `sizeof` operator has type `size_t` which is different from `int`: you should either case it as `(int)` or use the `printf` conversion specifier `%zu`.
- the `float` value should be initialized from a `float` constant: `float var1 = 3.145926535897932F;`
- the `long double` value should be initialized from a `long double` constant: `long double var1 = 3.145926535897932L;`
- In the call `printf("%.16f\n", var1)`, `var1` is implicitly converted to type `double` as specified for variable arguments in vararg functions. You might make this conversion explicit to silence this warning, showing the behavior is expected.
- the call `printf("%.21Lf\n", var3);` conforms to the C99 Standard, but the C library on your system seems incompatible with the compiler in use regarding the type `long double`.

Microsoft decided more than 10 years ago to map type `long double` to type `double` in their tools (cf [Why did Microsoft abandon long double data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120710/why-did-microsoft-abandon-long-double-data-type) ).

The compiler you use on your system seems to handle `long double` in a different way that is incompatible with the C library your program links to.  It is also possible that this library does not conform to the C99 specification, eg: the `%Ld` conversion for type `long double`, or uses a different ABI to pass `long double` values. Older Microsoft C libraries are known to have such problems decades after the C Standard was published. You should try and upgrade the system or switch to a conformant C development system.

Here is a modified version, that no longer has undefined behavior, but probably still won't produce the expected output on your system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float var1 = 3.145926535897932F;
    double var2 = 3.145926535897932;
    long double var3 = 3.14159265389793213456L;
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(float));
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(double));
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(long double));
    printf("%.16f\n", (double)var1);
    printf("%.16f\n", var2);
    printf("%.21Lf\n", var3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
8
16
3.1459264755249023
3.1459265358979320
3.141592653897931963769
```