# Does migrating code from vb.net to a C++ dll offer significant performance boosts?

Tags: c++, vb.net, performance, dll

I know simular questions have been asked before but I believe my specifics vary enough that this cam be it's own question. If I've missed another question that's very simular please link it for me.

I'm proficient in vb.net but a total novice at c++. I've got a subroutine in vb.net that just does a lot of maths. There's some trigonometry and squareroots etc. nothing too demanding *but* it's around 100 equations and they have to be run thousands of times.

Here's some pseudo code of what I do:

```
Sub mathsub()
For i = 0 to arraylength
A = somenum(i) * othernum(i)
...
Next
End sub
```

So I do all the math inside the for loop many thousands of times. Each time uses a different element of a bunch of arrays (somenum, othernum, etc.), all of these arrays are the same length.

No single line of code takes any significant length of time (when profiled each line takes a negligible length of time), but all in all the program takes longer than I'd like. **Can I expect a significant speed increase by rewriting this routeen in c++ and referencing it from vb.net?**

**Edit #1** - answers to questions in comments

The code takes a negligible amount of time per array element *but* there's about 20,000 elements and I need to do this about 10,000 times (so 200 million times - no joke). All in I've estimated it taking around 18 hours based on how long it takes for a fraction of the work. The entire program will need to be run multiple times as well, although each new run is 100% separate an unrelated. I have tried threading the code, I have a Ryzen 1800x 8 core (16 thread) processor - I've tried splitting the task into exactly 15 thread (leaving 1 thread for overhead and other activities) and using a parallel.for loop and both don't offer enough of an increase yet. I don't know what AVX is, but I'll start looking into it, I've never written a line of C++, but the maths itself is all just simple equations and I'm happy to spend a few days/weeks/months learning implementing if it's seriously going to make a difference!

Comment: How long does the VB code take to execute?  Even if you were to get a significant improvement, if the VB code executes quickly enough then it really isn't worth the effort.  For instance, a 50% increase in performance would be important if something takes an hour, could be important if something takes a minute but is likely not worth the effort if something takes a second.

Comment: The trig and math isn't going to be any faster, they are intrinsics in vb.net.  Might actually [be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687741/17034).  But you might well be ahead with the array manipulations, a C++ compiler doesn't generate bounds checks by default and might be able to auto-vectorize and auto-parallelize the code.

Comment: "I'm proficient in vb.net but a total novice at c++" probably means that you will write better vb than you would c++ ... it might be fun as a learning project though

Comment: Threading might be more relevant, ad that's available from vb.net as well. For serious speedups, you'd have to also use AVX, but that's not a realistic goal if you're a C++ novice.

Comment: I've answered the questions from comments in my edit to the question. Thank you all for your input, I hope my answers help explain my problem a little more!

Answer (score 0):

**Benchmark it**. There's no way to *know* that without benchmarking, but the answer is likely to be "yes" because of C++'s performance profile versus a managed language like VB.NET, but JIT optimizations, managed-to-native transitions, array access order / data locality, and general coding technique can all have an impact here.